# there are 2 regex rewrite but one of them is not working

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Theese are my rules. First one is working but second one is not.

It was working on my old server. I Just changed my server now its not working.

```
RewriteRule ^oyunlar/([0-9]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+) games.php?id=$1&amp;title=$2
RewriteRule ^post/([_0-9a-z-]+) post.php?up=$1
```

what could be wrong ?

on my php side, $_GET completely empty.

That is whole file;

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^uye user.php
RewriteRule ^oyunlar/([0-9]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+) games.php?id=$1&amp;title=$2
RewriteRule ^post/([_0-9a-z-]+) post.php?up=$1
RewriteRule ^tv tv.php
RewriteRule ^thumb timthumb2.php

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

and that is the url i requested: myurl.com/post/login

i'm checking status with charles. ^post part is working but querysting part is not.

edit: i just made i a couple tests, and actually both rules not working properly and somehow, my files can work without extension like: /hello.php or /hello

additional info: this is my own private server, debian lenny + ispCP

Comment: Please describe the situation more clearly. What is the actual requested URL? Does the appropriate page (post.php) execute? Are these the only rules?

Comment: sorry my bad, i've updated my question. post php content is ;
print_r($_GET);

Comment: Does it work if you remove the other rewrite rules?

Comment: unfortunately nothing changes.

Comment: I get this : post.php?up=login

Comment: you may try here: http://hengame.net/post/login i guess something about apache

Comment: now even more complicated: i just disabled rule, and it's still working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i've resolved my problem. it is occurs beacuse of **MultiViews**

somehow there was a rewrite and multiviews conflict. Simply i just disabled it from the .conf file.

Thank you people.

Answer (score 0):

@siniradam

Try changing your regex from this

```
([_0-9a-z-]+)
```

to this

```
([-_0-9a-z]+)
```

If a hyphen is supposed to be one of the allowed characters, it needs to be **first** in the list, not last.

Comment: thanks but nothing changed, but i findout something. i just removed .htaccess and and rewrites still working. im amused then i figured out my php can work without .php extension.